# Can header labels be translated in sonata admin bundle export feature?

Tags: symfony, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, sonata-admin, export-to-xml

SonataAdminBundle can export list data into several formats (CSV, Excel, JSON and XML), but the resulting file label headers exactly as the column names.

How can I replace those names for more describing labels? Usually by translating it as it's done in lists in screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've discovered the way. It's quite an obscure feature, but export headers (labels) can be overwritten by using keys in getExportFields method. And also there you can translate it.

```
public function getExportFields()
{
    return array(
        'field label 1' => 'field1',
        $this->trans('field label 2') => 'field2',
        'field label 3' => 'field3',
        [...]
    );
}
```